# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException spring

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, servlet

У меня есть проект посренный с использование MVC паттерна. Я решил перевести его на `spring`. Использую конфигурацию на `java`.  На данный момент я использовал конфигурационые файлы `java` в service и `dao` слоях. В `wep-app` слое пока что еще использую сервлеты и `web.xml`. Проблема в том что я не могу получить бины для дальнейшего использования в серлетах. Вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [] is defined
```

Как я понимаю она свидетльствует о том что я не могу получить свои бины. Помогите найти причину.

web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myapp.service.config.ServiceConfig</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

сервлет в котором я хочу получить `bean`(от него наследуются все остальные сервлеты)

```
public class BasicServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected Service<Account> accountService;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext applicationContext =
                WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(
                        this.getServletContext());
        this.accountService = applicationContext.getBean(AccountService.class);
    }
}
```

конфигурационый файл для сервис слоя

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan ("com.myapp.dao.config")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("accountService")
    public Service<Account> accountService(MainDao<Account> accountDao, SupportDao<Phone> phonesDao) {
        return new AccountService(accountDao, phonesDao);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

ну и сам `AccountService`

```
public class AccountService implements Service<Account> {

private MainDao<Account> accountDao;

private SupportDao<Phone> phoneDao;

@Autowired
public AccountService(MainDao<Account> accountDao, SupportDao<Phone> phoneDao) {
    this.accountDao = accountDao;
    this.phoneDao = phoneDao;
}

public AccountService() {
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void createAccount(Account obj) {
    List<Phone> phones = obj.getPhones();
    try {
        accountDao.create(obj);
        for (Phone item : phones) {
            phoneDao.create(item);
        }
    } catch (DaoException e) {
        throw new ServiceException(e);
    }
}
...остальные методы для работы с DAO слоем
}
```

Полный стек исключений

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet loginValidation threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.AccountService] is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1063)
com.myapp.servlets.BasicServlet.init(BasicServlet.java:25)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: 1. Приведи полный стек исключения. 2. Аннотация `@Autowired` на конструкторе `AccountService` лишняя. 3. Попробуй вместо `this.accountService = applicationContext.getBean(AccountService.class)` использовать `this.accountService = applicationContext.getBean(Service.class)`

Comment: Поставьте аннотацию `@Component` над `AccountService`. Spring пытается найти в контексте подходящий бин а его там нет. Спринг не знает что ваш сервис является бином